# Need a URI to be used in CursorLoader with SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

The constructor for a CursorLoader needs a URI but I don't know how to use it. From what I read I need a `ContentProvider`. But all I want to do is access my SQLite database. Can someone show me how to build a URI with a ContentProvider for this purpose? The documentation seems very complicated and show examples not related to a sqlite database.

Comment: "But all I want to do is access my SQLite database" -- you do not have to use `CursorLoader` to access a SQLite database.

Comment: @CommonsWare But if I'm using the database to return results to a `AutoCompleteTextView`, don't I need a `CursorLoader` to load the `Cursor` results?

Comment: No. You can call `query()` or `rawQuery()` on your `SQLiteDatabase`. Just do so on a background thread and think about configuration changes. Whether you use your own custom `AsyncTaskLoader`, or a retained fragment, or a singleton managed cache, or something else, is up to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you could point me to a tutorial doing exactly this or give me a skeleton code structure of how to set this up, that would be really really helpful. This is my first time using these classes so I'm unsure how to set this up correctly. So far I have my DB helper class setup to access the DB and I'm using a retained fragment for the entire view.

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsROWID is my baseline sample from my book on SQLite database access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) instead. Then you can perform your database query in **LoadInBackground** method

Comment: I will be querying my database to be used in a `AutoCompleteTextView` so don't I need a Cursor to be reading data from the results, and in turn need a CursorLoader?

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView can read data from an ArrayAdapter too, so you don't have to use a CursorAdapter or a CursorLoader